# Find top 3 max of a list and keep their positions on another list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I am building a program in Python for my uni essay and i am trying to find a way to find the top 3 max numbers from a list with floats, so i can keep their position in another list for future processing.

``````````
`maxim=max(listScore)
`i=0
`keep = [-1]*num
`for x in range(0,num):
````if listaScore[x]==maxim:
`````````keep[i]=x
`````````i+=1
`````````listScore[x]=-100
````maxim=max(listaScore)

the results i want is :

listScore=[0.25, 0.5, 0.5, -0.25, -0.25, 0.25]
positions=[1,2,5,-1,-1,-1]
``````````

Comment: Note that the logic followed for the first two output items, i.e if two items are the same you get the indices from the left to the right, the same should apply for `0.25`, so It'd make more sense if the output was `[1, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using a list comprehension. The idea is to [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) a `range` of the same length as the list, specifying that we want to fetch elements from the list in the`key` argument. What we get is the resulting sorted `range` to return us the indices that would sort the list:

```
l= [0.25, 0.5, 0.5, -0.25, -0.25, 0.25]
out = [i for i in sorted(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__, reverse=True)][:3]
# [1, 2, 0]
```

---

If you want the additional `-1s`:

```
out + [-1] * (len(l) - len(out))
# [1, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one slight tweak in @yatu's answer, little shorter:

```
print([i for i in sorted(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)][-3:])
```

Which gives:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Oops, seems like we went for the exact same approach here :)

Comment: @yatu I was trying to answer the same thing (saw this late, when i saw it you answered already), so i decided to tweak it, lol :-)